# Restricting file access of Docker container

Tags: node.js, file-permissions, docker

Suppose I have NodeJS application inside of Docker container. NodeJS can interact with host's filesystem using `fs` module. What I want is to give it access only to one folder (for example, */home/user1/thisfolder*), and deny reading/writing any other folder or file on my host. Is there a way to restrict such kind of access in Docker?

**UPD GOT ANSWER:**
Using AppArmor I could give `node` process only access to given directories, and when it tries to acces any other - it gets `permission denied`.

Comment: Just to be sure i understood you question well. You want to give your docker container access to a specific directory on your host?

Comment: If it means that my NodeJS code inside this container will also have access to a specific directory on my host - then yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you want to use is to mount a volume on the container using the -v option.

```
docker run -v /path/to/directory/on/your/host:/path/to/directory/on/your/container image CMD
```

It will let you access your volume.

More info : https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

If you want to restrict access to other part of your container you should use Apparmor from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, it helped me a bit. But I need to restrict access to other folders except this one. For instance, in nodejs code I can do `data = fs.readFileSync('./file1.txt','utf-8')` and receive file content into my variable `data` - that's OK. But something like `data = fs.readFileSync('/var/lib/anyfilehere.txt','utf-8')` should be restricted (throw exception or something).

Comment: I think the best way would be to use Apparmor. But it's not my specialty.

Comment: AppArmor was a perfect solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to add how you managed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Docker does not have access to the host filesystem unless you:

- map some path to a volume (as @Regan above suggested)
- run it in privileged mode

So, by default, docker is doing what you want.